# wcf per-call, http-binding - IDisposable pros cons

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

If I am using wcf service per-call mode and with http-binding
(not using multi-threading / thread in any method)
now If I implement IDisposible interface in my service
will there be any issue in performance?

Is it safe to implement IDisposible interface in this senerio?

I have done googling already but different-different articles makes me confuse.
so, if you can help I will be grateful.

Comment: Why do you need to implement IDisposable?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement IDisposable?  Or if there will be a performance hit?  or both?